# Proof verification on connected components

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

This is Problem 2, Section 3, Chapter 5 in Dugundji Topology

Let $A \subset Y$, where both $A$ and $Y$ are connected. Let $U$ be any set both open and closed in $Y - A$. Prove that $A \cup U$ is connected.

---

Let $U$, $V$ sets both open and closed in $Y - A$, and disjoint in $Y - A$. Now assume that $A \cup U$ is a union of two nonempty disjoint sets $S$ and $T$, both open and closed in $A \cup U$. Since $A$ is connected, without loss of generality we can tell that $A \subset S$, which implies that $(U - A) \subset T$. But as $U - A$ is both open and closed in $Y - A$, $U - A$ is equal to $T$. But then $S$ is empty relative to $Y - A$, which leads to a contradiction.

How does my proof look? Is there any gap in my proof?

Comment: What’s V? Otherwise looks fine at first glance.

Comment: Gaps: Why does $U$ clopen in $Y \setminus A$ imply $U = T$? What contradiction does $S \cap (Y \setminus A) = \emptyset$ lead to? [I've written $U$ rather than $U \setminus A$ as they are equal.]